# Azure blob storage "az storage copy" fails when having file with same name as folder inside the same directory

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have azure blob container contains a folder with name (data_source), now i'm trying to copy file with the same name to the same container, so i have both the file and the folder together with the same name.

I use this command:

```
az storage copy -s "$SRC" -d "$DEST" --recursive
```

**Note that i use --recursive because i have other folders to copy as well.**

The problem is, everything get copied successfully except the file with the same name as the folder in the container. I tried several ways even with the --recursive flag and didn't work.

May be the az storage copy is confusing files with directories, but i have no clue.

**Note: I cannot change the file name, they must be the same.**

Comment: Hi @Sameh, from where you are copying the file which have the same name as existing folder of target container?

Comment: From another storage account

Answer (score 0):

I created two folders with same name and same blob file name with same contents. I changed one value inside one of my blob file keeping the blob file and folder name same as the other folder and blob file present in another storage account and performed copy operation like below:-

Storage account **`venkat123`** with same folder and file, but file has one extra value **test** added, Refer below: -

**Portal:**

[image]

Storage Account **`venkat326`** has the same folder data_source and file data_source.json but does not contain **`test`** value, refer below:-

**Portal:**

[image]

Now, I used the **`az storage copy`** command to copy the folders with same names and the content with value test was added from venkat123 storage account to venkat326 storage account like below:-

**Command:-**

```
az storage copy -s "https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/test/data_source/data_source.json<SAS-token>" -d "https://venkat326.blob.core.windows.net/demo/data_source/data_source.json<SAS-token>" --recursive
```

Output:-
[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the try and detailed answer.. what you demonstrated would work indeed, the issue happens if you moved the file outside the folder, so both the file and the folders in the same level directly inside the container. Note that the file should has no extension. I.e. data_souce

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible.